# Counting newlines or carriage returns but not both

Tags: command-line

If I do this on a Mac file, I get the correct number of lines but I get double the lines on unix files:

```
cat /path/to/file.txt | tr '\r' '\n' | wc -l
```

If I do this on a unix file, I get the correct number of lines but zero lines on a Mac file:

```
cat /path/to/file.txt | wc -l
```

How do I get the correct number of lines in a single command no matter what the file system origin (Linux, Mac, Windows)?

Comment: Macs use `\n` starting from Mac OS X 10.0 (2001). Do you really get ancient Mac files with `\r`?

Comment: @Melebius yes, when dealing with Mac version of Excel.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to inspect the files you're handling w.r.t. which line feed style that is used in them.

> $ od -t x1z

will print the file content in hex bytes and "ASCII", look for 0A and 0D bytes.

I have a bash function that gets defined in ~/.profile/ or ~/.bashrc to help with this kind of issues:

```
function od-crlf {
#DOC echo "od-crlf FILE - displays file contents in HEX w CR+LF chars emphasized"

  od -Ax -t x1z -w32 $@ \
  | sed -re 's/(0a)/\x1b[44m\1\x1b[m/g;s/(0d)/\x1b[45m\1\x1b[m/g'
}
```